# Validation of viewstate MAC failed. in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If
>   this application is hosted by a Web
>   Farm or cluster, ensure that
>    configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation
>   algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used
>   in a cluster.

I have tried disabling viewstate on main page and on the thickbox.

This is happening when clicking an asp.net button on a query ui pop up box.

Trying to redirect back to the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had disabled the EnableViewState, but not the EnableViewStateMac field.

All sorted thanks for the help mate.

Berty

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't updated to 3.5SP1 right? The error usually occurs when clicking a link before the page is fully loaded which causes problems with the __EVENTVALIDATION field. [See this page on MSDN for a more detailed explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx)

And here's a [link to 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en)

Comment: I have left the page for a while to fully load and i do have SP1 already installed